# Where did "Always use Y-Up axis" in Xcode 8 go?

Tags: xcode, 3d, scenekit

We used to have an option "Always use Y-Up axis" toggle in Xcode (until Xcode 7 at least, I think).
It's gone in current Xcode 8.2.1, and probably gone since 8.1 or even 8.0. Why? Or is it hiding somewhere else? Any workarounds?

**Update:** I found a related quote from a WWDC speech, way back in 2014:

> The way you add 3D assets to your game is just SceneKit asset
>   catalogs.
>
> SceneKit asset catalogs are new feature in Xcode 6, SceneKit asset
>   catalogs are new feature in Xcode 6, and they allow you to organize
>   and optimize your 3D assets.
>
> The structure of SceneKit asset catalogs is preserved when they are
>   copied into your target.
>
> Also, they automatically track files that are added to them or removed
>   from them on disc.
>
> They are really convenient because they can optimize your 3D assets
>   for you.
>
> For instance, they help with up axis conversion.
>
> SceneKit follows the up axis conversion, which means that the positive
>   y axis is the one that looks up.
>
> This is a convention that is followed by many other applications and
>   frameworks, but some exporters do things differently and use a z up
>   axis convention.
>
> With SceneKit asset catalogs, you don't have to think about that.
>
> We automatically and transparently convert all the animations and
>   geometries in your scene so that they follow the up axis convention.

Taken from http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/610
Video at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/610/

The above seems to describe the scene kit asset catalog when it was introduced. It doesn't actually answer my question here; why that feature is removed from current Xcode. I can also confirm that no conversion happens behind the scenes. A model exported from Blender is always going to move closer to or away from camera if its Y position is changed. At run-time it is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode 8, you can Ctrl-click on the .scnasset folder and Open As > SceneKit Catalog.  If you make any changes, it will write out a Settings.json file.  This may be what you are looking for.

[image: Asset Catalog Settings in XCode 8]